# Club all the rows of a dataframe as others except one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset

```
       Item Type     market_share
    Office Supplies     10
     Baby Food          20
  Vegetables            10
       Meat             30
 Personal Care          10
   Household            20
```

I want to club all the rows except Baby Food column so that my dataset will look like

```
       Item Type     market_share
      Others            80
     Baby Food          20
```

How can I do that, basically club all the rows,sum them and put them as others.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
df.groupby(df['Item Type'].eq('Baby Food').map({True:'Baby Food',False:'Others'})).sum()
```

---

```
            market_share
Item Type              
Baby Food            20
Others               80
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `array` or `Series` by condition or by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and convert missing values to `NaN` and aggregate `sum`:

```
s = np.where(df['Item Type'] == 'Baby Food', 'Baby Food', 'Others')
print (s)
['Others' 'Baby Food' 'Others' 'Others' 'Others' 'Others']
```

---

```
s = df['Item Type'].map({'Baby Food':'Baby Food'}).fillna('Others')
print (s)
0       Others
1    Baby Food
2       Others
3       Others
4       Others
5       Others
Name: Item Type, dtype: object

df = df.groupby(s)['market_share'].sum().rename_axis('Item Type').reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
   Item Type  market_share
0  Baby Food            20
1     Others            80
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
df['market_share_2'] = np.where(df['Item Type'].values=='Baby Food', 'Baby Food', 'Others')
```

**Output**

```
         Item Type  market_share market_share_2
0  Office Supplies            10         Others
1        Baby Food            20      Baby Food
2       Vegetables            10         Others
3             Meat            30         Others
4    Personal_Care            10         Others
5        Household            20         Others
```

Then use `value_counts()` -

```
df['market_share_2'].value_counts()

Others       5
Baby Food    1
Name: market_share_2, dtype: int64
```

**TLDR;**

```
pd.Series(np.where(df['Item Type'].values=='Baby Food', 'Baby Food', 'Others')).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the except function `!=` and the is function `==`.

```
df[df['market_share'] != 'Baby Food'].sum()

df[df['market_share'] == 'Baby Food'].sum()
```